# can not see image through the tableHeaderView, UITalbleView, ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to see my image through tableHeaderView by following

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    UIView *tableHeaderView         =   [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 180.0)];
    tableHeaderView.backgroundColor =   [UIColor clearColor];
    UIView *blackBorderView         =   [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 179.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 1.0)];
    blackBorderView.backgroundColor =   [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.0 blue: 0.0 alpha: 0.8];
    [tableHeaderView addSubview: blackBorderView];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView  =   tableHeaderView;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.backgroundColor  =   [UIColor clearColor];



    _headerImageYOffset             =  0;
    _headerImage                    =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"myImage.png"]];
    CGRect headerImageFrame         =  _headerImage.frame;
    headerImageFrame.origin.y       =  _headerImageYOffset;
    _headerImage.frame = headerImageFrame;
    [self.view insertSubview: _headerImage belowSubview: self.tableView];

}
```

However, the image is not visible at all. I think `clearColor` can help me see the image.

If I modify the position of ny table view in xib and running the codes, I can see partial of the image

[image]

If you have any ideas about this, please help

Answer (score 0):

The table's background isn't transparent, try

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0 ]];
```

Comment: true, based on the question I'm quessing eventually they will want it semi transparent

Comment: another option would be.. [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0]

Comment: yeah.. now he can really pick the solution, he likes most ;-)